# sails 0.9.8 not work, when created controller and lift it

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a problem with sails 0.9.8. I already installed sails on my mac and also lift, it work well, but when start generate controller and model then start lift command again it show some error like:

```
$sails lift

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/index.js:68
    var schemaAttributes = this.waterline.schema[this.identity].attributes;
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at _.extend._initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/index.js:68:49)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/index.js:45:8)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/collection/index.js:57:8)
    at new child (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/extend.js:17:39)
    at instantiateCollection (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:174:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at Object.async.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:107:9)
    at Hook.startORM (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:164:10)
    at Array.bound [as 1] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:462:46)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:416:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at Object.taskComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:415:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting from Waterline, it looks like a problem with your global Sails' dependencies.  That's not the right version of Waterline for Sails 0.9.8.  This can happen if you've been trying out other versions of Sails; the npm cache gets a little muddied-up.  To correct it, do the following:

1. `sudo npm uninstall sails -g`
2. `npm cache clear`
3. `sudo npm install sails -g`

That will reinstall Sails with all of the correct dependencies.  You shouldn't have to change your project.

Answer (score 0):

You may just be missing some modules. For example, if basic dependencies are installed globally with something like `sudo npm install sails -g`, newly generated Sails app will lift without any problems, but as soon as you start adding some functionality, it may required other modules (probably, DB adapter-related in your case).

Long story short, just run `npm install` from within your project folder, it will create a `node_modules` subfolder and install project's dependencies in it.

Comment: you are right, but I think because of my model that is validated from waterline.so how can i fixe this?

Comment: Did you try running `npm install` from within your project folder? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem today. Reinstalling Sails globally didn't work for me because I had two copies of Sails installed. Deleting the locally installed copy forced Node to use the globally installed copy of Sails and all its dependencies which did fix everything.