# Error on sails lift since update to 0.10.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm working on a project that was originally made with sails 0.9.8.something and was recently updated to 0.10.4. I've received errors while trying to run `sails lift` since then. Here's the error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './Sails'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mjbrender/Documents/Development/session86/node_modules/sails/lib/app/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

To confirm, I've updated locally:

```
$ sails -v
0.10.4
```

And after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334716/sails-0-9-8-not-work-when-created-controller-and-lift-it), I deleted and updated as recommended. Still no luck. Any clue what's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install sails **locally** in your project directory as well. Delete the `node_modules/sails` folder and run `npm install sails` in the root directory of your application. See if this solves the issue.

A rough migration guide can also be found [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/version-notes/0.10.x/Changelog0.10x.md)

Comment: Exactly - you hit it on the head. I ran installations globally but not locally. Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite the case that you *have* to have Sails installed locally in your project.  You can remove the *node_modules/sails* folder entirely and still run `sails lift` if you have Sails installed globally (but not `node app.js`).  What is true is that *if* you have Sails installed locally in your project, then that's the copy that will be used when you run `sails lift`--not the global one!

Comment: The link in your answer is broken